# Under which circumstances is it better NOT to choose alpine version of a third party docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm working on an app. My app uses Postgres. I made a docker image for my app and now I'm building a docker compose that has my-app-image and postgres images.

I noticed there's a Postgres alpine image, but all examples I see are using regular Postgres image.

I get that if I'm developing a Docker image for myapp, I might get into trouble by using alpine because some package is not available or something.

But regarding Postgres, wouldn't it be safe to assume alpine postgres works the same as regular postgres?

Why would you choose regular postgres over alpine postgres since the image is smaller and probably less resource consuming?

(I'm using postgres as an example, but I guess the question is the same for any other third party image)

Comment: From Postgres's [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres): _"Also of note, Alpine-based variants do not support locales; see "Character sets and locale" in the musl documentation for more details."_ _"When using the Alpine variants, any postgres extension not listed in postgres-contrib will need to be compiled in your own image"_

Comment: Thanks for the info I didn't see that. So I assume these alpine images can have various degrees of incompatibilities/caveats depending on the application?

Comment: I'd think so, yes.